# Launch a program in another directory via Pexpect

Tags: python, bash, pexpect

I am working on a Python script that controls a C cli program via Pexpect module.
The script and the program are placed in different directories. I could just specify the absolute path to the program, however there is a problem:

The program is highly dependent on the directory you run it from: say, if you run it using bash, you have to be in the exact dir it is placed in, otherwise it will fail.

As I understand, by default `pexpect.spawn()` sees the dir it is run from as the "current directory" for the emulated shell.

What can I do to make it work, apart from putting the script and the program together?

btw, Python is 2.7.6, pexpect==3.3, bash shell

Comment: As per the [docs](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html), `spawn` has a `cwd` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pexpect.spawn()`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html?highlight=spawn#pexpect.spawn) accepts a `cwd` argument, could you set that to the desired directory?

```
pexpect.spawn(<cmd>, cwd="<path>")
```

may give you what you want

Comment: That seems to be it. Can't find it in the docs though. Thank you!

Comment: @egor You can see it at https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html?highlight=spawn#pexpect.spawn

Comment: I have another question. Your suggestion seems to work fine, but not always. I have problems spawning my own cli programs from different directories. I get the `pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: ./helloworld.` when run from a different directory, disregarding the cwd parameters

Comment: @Egor that might be better asked as another question, and if you can try to narrow down when do it work and not work.  As a though, which I have not verified, it's possible that `spawn` is using your current environment to find the command to invoke, but modifying the environment of that process so it has the proper `cwd`.  It's probably an "order of operations" type problem